# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR match words delimited by newline "\n"

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I'm trying to split the string "SMITH\nALLEN\WARD\nJONES" in Oracle 10g by newline "\n" using a single SELECT query. Please help me to find the exact Regular Expression for this.

**Expected Output:**

```
1 SMITH
2 ALLEN\WARD
3 JONES
```

I have tried the expression "[^\n]+", but I got the following result which considered "\" as well. I want the expression to consider only "\n".

**Query:**

```
    SELECT   REGEXP_SUBSTR ('SMITH\nALLEN\WARD\nJONES',
                            '[^\n]+',
                            1,
                            LEVEL)
      FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY   REGEXP_SUBSTR ('SMITH\nALLEN\WARD\nJONES',
                            '[^\n]+',
                            1,
                            LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

**Result:**

```
1 SMITH
2 ALLEN
3 WARD 
4 JONES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `[]` the characters are matched individually, and `\n` isn't seen a special character or even a run of characters anyway - it matches either of those characters individually; so even changing to `[^\\n]` wouldn't help.

You can use this form, which also returns empty elements:

```
select regexp_substr('SMITH\nALLEN\WARD\nJONES', '(.*?)(\\n|$)', 1, level, 'm', 1)
from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('SMITH\nALLEN\WARD\nJONES', '\\n') + 1;

REGEXP_SUBSTR('SMITH\NAL
------------------------
SMITH
ALLEN\WARD
JONES
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked !! I searched for a solution everywhere, but didn't find a similar question. Thanks again @Alex for the quick response..

Comment: In the regexp_count() function, '\n' should be changed to '\\n' as it will count 'n' character as well.

Comment: @KeshanFernando - thanks, yes; didn't make a difference here, but would if any of the values had a lower-case n.